# Configuring asp.net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using this code for routing in `RouteConfig.cs` :

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now i want to change it, if the url is `"<domain>/Saman/Profile"`, i should load the profile page for the user that `username` is `"Saman"`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to give profile route before the default route.here url will look for the  profile once it's find it will use the first route.i hope this will work.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Profile",
            url: "FilesView/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FilesView", action = "Profile", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FilesView", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: In your solution url is like this : <domain>/profile/user
But i want to when url is <domain>/saman/profile , search for "saman" username, and get profile properties.

Comment: can you try with adding {name}/Profile.here it will expect name/profile.

Comment: I don't think that `name = UrlParameter.Optional` is good in this case. Should it really be optional here?

Comment: no but if you have one more action in same controller then which will return all the users for the profile then we could use the same route with out adding new route but in that case route should be like profile/{name} here name is optional.

Comment: Are you sure this solution could be working?
I'm using this code, but i get 404 error ...

Comment: @SamanGholami i have updated my post. you can do it in FilesView controller by just specifying  action is profile.example : http://localhost/FilesView/name=profilename.Sorry i hope it will work